# Authentication in AngleSharp

Tags: authentication, kerberos, anglesharp

I need to parse a website but this one has Windows authentication (kerberos), I authenticated with `HttpRequester` but How can I pass the authentication to AngleSharp?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
req.CookieContainer = session;
```

After that, I don't know how to continue to pass the session to `AngleSharp` connection:

```
var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
await context.OpenAsync(WebsiteUrl);
```

Comment: This question is a bit broad for the StackOverflow format. Can you please show a relevant code or config file snippet - basically, an [mcve].  Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to NuGet the AngleSharp.Io package, that will enable the "WithRequesters"

And then:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
var config = Configuration.Default.WithRequesters(handler).WithCookies();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(url)
```